# storing list items to shared preferences flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a list of items which has a default value as false and i am using a checkbox to change the selected item to true, then i am try to add the true key to a list in the shared preferences, but i am getting an error message of 'The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'
thank you all

```
class BallGames extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BallGamesState createState() => new BallGamesState();
}

class BallGamesState extends State {
  Map<String, bool> List = {
    'Bubble Football ⚽': false,
    'Futsal ': false,
    'Beach Volleyball ': false,
    'Volleyball ': false,
    'Dodgeball ': false,
    'Rugby ': false,
    'American Footbal ': false,
    'Korftbal ': false,
    'Netbal ⚾': false,
  };

  



  getItems() {
    List.forEach((key, value) async {
      if (value == true) {
        
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      
        prefs.setStringList('selectedGames', key); //the 'key' is underline as the error value
        // the error message: 'The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>''
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wanted to store the list but you sent `string` instead of `List<String>`.

```
List<String> holder_1;

  getItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == true) {
        holder_1.add(key);
      }
    });
    prefs.setStringList('selectedGames', holder_1);
   
}
```

Comment: okay. thanks alot . i tried it now. but i got this error ' The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'.  .... the holder_1 is underline as the error

Comment: `var holder_1 = [];` change to  `List<String> holder_1 = [];` otherwise, change this line `prefs.setStringList('selectedGames', holder_1 as List<String>);`

Comment: hi i got an error message of .  List isn't a type. The instance member 'List' can't be accessed in an initializer. thank you

Comment: can you share `setStringList('selectedGames', holder_1);` part's code

Comment: List<String> holder_1 = [ ];

  getItems() async {

    
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == true) {
        holder_1.add(key);
      }
    });
    prefs.setStringList('selectedGames', holder_1);
  }

Comment: List<String> holder_1; remove initialization

Comment: that is all the shared preference setString, aside from the importing the library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240003/discussion-between-jahidul-islam-and-techwithyo).

Comment: List<String> holder_1; is still showing the same here as List is not a type